# Delete/Change Error handler for PHP uploading which forces user to upload file

Tags: php

Hi i have a program that allows user to upload a jpeg. and then do something about the file. my problem is that when there is no file upload, it displays an error handler and tells the user to upload a file. i dont want it to be like that. ***what i what to do is for the process to continue even there is no file uploaded***. how can i do this? below is my code. i think some part of it is doing the restriction. i dont know which part to delete or change here. please help me find out i've been working on it for days now. thank you so much.

```
    // make a note of the current working directory, relative to root.
    $directory_self = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

    // make a note of the directory that will recieve the uploaded files //i made it as the same directory where the .php file is
    $uploadsDirectory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $directory_self;

    // make a note of the location of the upload form in case we need it
    $uploadForm = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory_self . 'index.php';

    // make a note of the location of the success page
    $uploadSuccess = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory_self . 'upload.success.php';

    // name of the fieldname used for the file in the HTML form
    $fieldname = 'file';

    // possible PHP upload errors
    $errors = array(1 => 'php.ini max file size exceeded', 
                    2 => 'html form max file size exceeded', 
                    3 => 'file upload was only partial', 
                    4 => 'no file was attached');

    // check the upload form was actually submitted else print form
    isset($_POST['submit'])
        or error('the upload form is neaded', $uploadForm);

    // check for standard uploading errors
    ($_FILES[$fieldname]['error'] == 0)
        or error($errors[$_FILES[$fieldname]['error']], $uploadForm);

    // check that the file we are working on really was an HTTP upload
    @is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'])
        or error('not an HTTP upload', $uploadForm);

    // validation... since this is an image upload script we 
    // should run a check to make sure the upload is an image
    @getimagesize($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'])
        or error('only image uploads are allowed', $uploadForm);

    // make a unique filename for the uploaded file and check it is 
    // not taken... if it is keep trying until we find a vacant one
    $now = time();
    while(file_exists($uploadFilename = $uploadsDirectory.$now.'-'.$_FILES[$fieldname]['name']))
    {
        $now++;
    }

    // now let's move the file to its final and allocate it with the new filename
    @move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'], $uploadFilename)
        or error('receiving directory insuffiecient permission', $uploadForm);

    SOME CODE HERE THAT CHECKS IF THERE OR NO FILE IS UPLOADED AND DO THE PROCESS

    // make an error handler which will be used if the upload fails
    function error($error, $location, $seconds = 5)
    {
        header("Refresh: $seconds; URL=\"$location\"");
        echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"'."\n".
        '"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">'."\n\n".
        '<html lang="en">'."\n".
        '   <head>'."\n".
        '       <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">'."\n\n".
        '       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">'."\n\n".
        '   <title>Upload error</title>'."\n\n".
        '   </head>'."\n\n".
        '   <body>'."\n\n".
        '   <div id="Upload">'."\n\n".
        '       <h1>Upload failure</h1>'."\n\n".
        '       <p>An error has occured: '."\n\n".
        '       <span class="red">' . $error . '...</span>'."\n\n".
        '       The upload form is reloading</p>'."\n\n".
        '    </div>'."\n\n".
        '</html>';
        exit;
    } // end error handler
```

Comment: Which of the error messages do you get which you don't want to have?

Comment: `@move_uploaded_file` returns a `BOOL` whether or not the file was moved successfully, if that helps.

Comment: @Luceos this error appears `An error has occured: no file was attached... The upload form is reloading` meaning it it forcing the user to upload a file bec. the process wont continue if there is no file upload. which i dont want to happen. i want it to be just fine if there is no file uploaded. thanks

Comment: @SuperScript what can i do about it? how does it affect the behavior of the program? thanks for further help

Answer (score 0):

So instead of using an uploaded version, you'd prefer a separate file to be used.

In your code:

```
// check for standard uploading errors
($_FILES[$fieldname]['error'] == 0)
    or error($errors[$_FILES[$fieldname]['error']], $uploadForm);
```

Change that to something like:

```
// check for standard uploading errors
if($_FILES[$fieldname]['error'] > 0 && $_FILES[$fieldname]['error'] != 4)
    error($errors[$_FILES[$fieldname]['error']], $uploadForm);
// your error is caused by the "no file was attached", let's skip that error
if($_FILES[$fieldname]['error'] == 4)
    // select your default image and skip all uploading steps
```

Hope this helps you more on your way.

Comment: how can i select my default image? lets say i have default.jpg in the same directory where the .php file is. thanks again for further help

Comment: still there? If not too much to ask can you help me further with this as i am having a hard time trying to do it. thansk you so much

Comment: i tried it but still, it's not continuing with the process. thank u